# Hot to integrate Meta(Facebook) Audience Network binding with Admob?

Tags: android, admob, facebook-audience-network

Based on my understanding those are the required steps to integrated binding Audience Network:

1. [Completed the Audience Network Setup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/bidding/partner-mediation/audience-network-setup)
2. [Integrating Facebook Audience Network with Mediation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/facebook?fbclid=IwAR3tzpTPtkcHO1Js60Qvr6Rgujh5ZozgSXoctvIqv37wnfPABkbjeNHY0Cs)
3. [Add a Network Security Configuration File](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-network-security-config)

I am implementing native ads, and there is one extra step for it that I don't understand

The docs says:

> Some Facebook native ad assets don't map one to one to Google native
> ad assets. Such assets are passed back to the publisher in a bundle in
> getExtras() method in NativeAd. Here's a code example showing how to
> extract these assets:

```
Bundle extras = nativeAd.getExtras();
if (extras.containsKey(FacebookAdapter.KEY_SOCIAL_CONTEXT_ASSET)) {
    String socialContext = extras.get(FacebookAdapter.KEY_SOCIAL_CONTEXT_ASSET);
    ...
}
```

What am I supposed to do with the `socialContext`? Also, it's an object and not a string.

At moment, I am getting Admobs ads, but for Meta, I am able to make binding requests and have some fill rate, but there are no impressions. All the rest is green.

In the [Publisher Onboarding Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/property/checklist/?property_id=1391845241272924) it shows that I don't properly integrate the impressions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

About `KEY_SOCIAL_CONTEXT_ASSET`, I've got some data about it (reported via Crashlytics). My conclusions for now, based on the samples I got:

1. It is a string
2. For most cases, it's a website URL, yet for some reason in upper-case. Example: "UNIPOLHOME.IT"
3. In other cases, it's just a message. Example is : "FREE · Open in app"
4. I think this could fit in sub-title text, if it's not available...

As for the fill-rate and no-impressions, that's something I still don't understand. Facebook is supposed to be a competitor of Admob&Google. Should have it as easy as possible, yet it seems the complete opposite...